# Change the background of a border if the textbox inside that border contains text from my search textbox

Tags: wpf, binding, triggers, textbox

I would like to create some XAML that highlights a textbox, when the textbox contains text from another textbox. It's essentially highlighting searched items.

UI:
[image: Here is my UI:]

When a user types anything into the Search textbox on the bottom left of the UI, it filters the workstations from the treeview until the only ones left contain the search term in there details. When they then select a treeview item, it populates the details on the right. I'd like if it highlighted the textbox that contains the search term as shown on the workstation name field above.

Here is some of my code:

The textbox with a hardcoded highlight

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
    <Border Name="HighlightBorder" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="4">
         <Border.Background>
              <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="1" RadiusY="0.7">
                   <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                   <GradientStop Color="#FFFFEA00"/>
              </RadialGradientBrush>
         </Border.Background>

         <TextBox Margin="5" Height="32" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding WorkstationName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

The Search Textbox:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <TextBlock Text="Search:" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"/>
     <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SearchCriteria, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
```

Is there an easy way to only have the border have that gradient background when the textbox contains the string in the search textbox and otherwise, be black? I'd love to have it be a XAML only solution, but I'm not stubborn about it either.

I also think it would be neat to have the background pulse a little, but I can fight to figure out my own animations, I really just need help with my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need a little bit of code in the form of a converter

```
public class ContainsSearchTextConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Any(v => v == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
            return null;

        var text = values[0].ToString();

        var search = values[1].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
            return null;

        if (text.Contains(search))
            return "true";

        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You then use it like:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Border Name="HighlightBorder" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="4">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Value="true">
                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource containsSearchTextConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="workStationNameTextBox" Path="Text" />
                                    <Binding Path="SearchCriteria" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <Setter Property="Background" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                        <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="1" RadiusY="0.7">
                                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFEA00"/>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>

            <TextBox Name="workStationNameTextBox" Background="Black" Margin="5" Height="32" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding WorkstationName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and correct response! The only thing I had to figure out for myself that a beginner might have a harder time with is defining the converter in the resources, "<local:ContainsSearchTextConverter x:Key="ContainsSearchTextConverter"/>"

Comment: If I wanted to pop that style out of the border and make it a resource to use on other borders, as well, is there some kind of RelativeSource binding I could replace the hard coded ElementName ("workStationNameTextBox") with?

Comment: Not that I know of.  To remove the need for an ElementName though, you are probably better off just encapsulating it all in a user control.  If you are feeling adventourous you could get rid of the border altogether and look at implementing a glow effect on you textbox using HLSL.